# Arduino opening SD filename as string

Tags: c++, file-io, arduino

I am trying to open up a file that I calculate the name into a string.  However, it is just giving me compile errors as shown.

```
for(int i=1;;i++)
{
   String temp = "data";
   temp.concat(i);
   temp.concat(".csv");
   if(!SD.exists(temp))//no matching function for call to sdclass::exists(String&)
   {
      datur = SD.open(temp,FILE_WRITE);
   }
}
```

I am a java person, so I don't see why this isn't working.  I tried a few string object methods but none seem to have worked.  I am a bit new at arduino programming but I understand java much better.  The point of this for loop is to make a new file each time the arduino reboots.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SD.open` expects a character array instead of a `String`, you need to convert it using the [`toCharArray`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray) method first. Try

```
  char filename[temp.length()+1];
  temp.toCharArray(filename, sizeof(filename));
  if(!SD.exists(filename)) { 
   ...
  }
```

Completed Code:

```
for(int i=1;;i++)
{
   String temp = "data";
   temp.concat(i);
   temp.concat(".csv");
   char filename[temp.length()+1];
   temp.toCharArray(filename, sizeof(filename));
   if(!SD.exists(filename))
   {
      datur = SD.open(filename,FILE_WRITE);
      break;
   }
}
```

You will find a number of functions take char arrays instead of strings.

Comment: Why can't these functions accept a `const char*` such as the one returned by `temp.c_str()`? That would make life so much easier. The SD.exists function is not intended to change the filename anyway.